# Form layout to call JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, forms, layout

I'm writing a Java Swing program that needs to enable the user to select 8 different colors from a Settings form. This is quite straightforward as far as it goes with JColorChooser, but I'm wondering is there a recommended way to lay out the form. This is what I'm currently contemplating:

1. For each color,
2. Display a square in the current selected color,
3. Display to the right of that, a button that will bring up the JColorChooser to change the selected color.

However, I suspect the 8 buttons will make the form look clunky if not downright ugly (particularly if more get added later). An alternative approach might be to make the square double as the button; in that case, how to visually indicate it's clickable?

Is there an alternative recommended method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `ColorButton` that I use in the pscode API.

```
package org.pscode.ui.widget;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** Provides a button for popping a color chooser.
The Color can be obtained by calling ColorButton.getBackground().
@author Andrew Thompson. */
public class ColorButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private JColorChooser chooseColor;
    private String htmlColor;

    private String text;

    public ColorButton(String label) {
        super(label);
        text = label;
        chooseColor = new JColorChooser();
        addActionListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        super.setText(
            "<html><body style='text-align: left;'><center>" +
            "<p>" +
            text +
            "<br>" +
            "<span style='width: 5px; height: 5px; " +
            "border: solid 1px black; background-color: " +
            htmlColor +
            "; color: " +
            htmlColor +
            ";'>AA</span>  " +
            "</center></body></html>");
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Color c = chooseColor.showDialog(
            this,
            "Choose Color",
            getBackground() );
        if (c!=null) {
            setBackground(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        super.setBackground( new Color(bg.getRed(), bg.getGreen(), bg.getBlue()) );
        int r = bg.getRed();
        int g = bg.getGreen();
        int b = bg.getBlue();

        htmlColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
        setText(text);
    }
}
```

### Screenshot

Screenshot of typical usage.

[image: Color scheme chooser using ColorButtons]

### In Other News..

> @rwallace: how did you get them to be all the same shape (regardless of length of caption)..

That part of the layout (for the 5 buttons and check box) is using a `GridLayout`.  You might also alter the size of the buttons by:

1. Setting the preferred size (dangerous to presume we can second guess it).
2. Adding some padding in the style for the `body` element of the HTML.

> "..and with the slightly rounded corners and shiny effect?"

*DukeBox* (from which that screenshot was obtained) uses the native PLAF - I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Andrew Thompson, uuuppps gooood +1

Comment: Is good, thanks! But how did you get them to be all the same shape (regardless of length of caption) and with the slightly rounded corners and shiny effect? When I create some just by calling the constructor, they just come out as plain rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider implementing the `Icon` interface and using the icon on the button. Together, `PieceButton` and `ColorIcon` comprise an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).