# Set Discriminate Tool-Tips With Different Background Colors (Java)

Tags: java, swing, colors, label, tooltip

I have a program with two sets of tooltips:

- Normal Tooltips that describe a JLabel in more depth
- Tooltips that signify errors - these should have a red background color.

I know how to set the background color of a tooltip by using UIManager, but that changes the background of all of the tooltips, something that I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can [*Use HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), including tool tips.

Addendum: There's a nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412817).

Comment: This worked.  I was not aware that one could use simple CSS in Swing components.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom mouse listener that would display the other tool-tip.

However, this sounds a little confusing to the user.

Comment: I need the two categories of ToolTips to have different background colors.  The display event shouldn't change.

Comment: Do you want to show both at the same time? Does the error message take precedence?